# Triggers - Saldo insuficiente

Tags: sql-server

Aclaro que estoy empezando con los triggers. Sucede que tengo 2 tablas: Viajes y Tarjetas, ambas están relacionadas con una foreign key, en este caso el **Numero_Tarjeta** de tipo varchar(16).
Estaba haciendo un ejercicio y llegue hasta el paso 3, que es el de **- Registre el viaje**

A continuación dejo mi ejercicio:

1. Realizar un trigger que al agregar un viaje:

- Verifique que la tarjeta se encuentre activa.
- Verifique que el saldo de la tarjeta sea suficiente para realizar el viaje.
- Registre el viaje
- Registre el movimiento
- Descuente el stock de la tarjeta

```css
Create Trigger TR_AgregarViaje On Viajes
After insert 
As 
Begin
    Begin Try
        Begin Transaction
            Declare @Estado bit
            Declare @Saldo money
            Declare @CostoDelViaje money
            Declare @Numero_Tarjeta varchar(16)
            Declare @CodigoViaje varchar(16)
            Declare @FechaHoraViaje datetime
            Declare @NumeroInternoColectivo bigint
            Declare @CodigoLinea bigint
            Declare @ID_Usuario bigint
            -- Accedo al número de tarjeta a través de la tabla 'inserted', ya que el registro está guardado ahí, al ser de tipo 'insert'
            Select @Numero_Tarjeta = Numero_Tarjeta, @CostoDelViaje = Importe, @CodigoViaje = CodigoViaje, @ID_Usuario = ID_Usuario,
            @NumeroInternoColectivo = NumeroInternoColectivo, @CodigoLinea = CodigoLinea From inserted
            -- Busco el estado y saldo
            Select @Estado = @Estado, @Saldo = Saldo From Tarjetas Where @Numero_Tarjeta = 442983422

            

            -- Verificó
            if @Estado = 1 
            Begin
                if @Saldo>=@CostoDelViaje
                Begin
                    Insert into Viajes(CodigoViaje,FechaHoraViaje,NumeroInternoColectivo,CodigoLinea,Numero_Tarjeta,Importe,ID_Usuario)
                    values (@CodigoViaje,getdate(),@NumeroInternoColectivo,@CodigoLinea,@Numero_Tarjeta,@CostoDelViaje,@ID_Usuario)
                End
            End
 
 
        Commit Transaction
    End Try
    Begin Catch
        RollBack Transaction
    End Catch
End
```

Estoy intentando registrar los viajes que tengan una tarjeta con estado tipo true o 1, hasta acá lo pude hacer. Después estoy verificando que el saldo de la tarjeta sea suficiente para pagar el costo del viaje, hice un select a la tabla tarjetas para saber el saldo que tiene.
Al hacer el insert a la tabla Viajes con un costo superior al saldo me lo inserta, pero no debería ser así. No sé en que me estoy equivocando, alguna ayuda?
Aun no hice los demás pasos xp estoy trancando con esas validaciones

Acá dejo el script de la db:

```css
Create database Colectivos
go
Use Colectivos
go
Create Table Usuarios(

    ID_Usuario bigint not null primary key identity(1,1),
    Apellido varchar(100) not null,
    Nombres varchar(100) not null,
    Dni bigint not null unique,
    FechaPrimerSube date null,
    Saldo money null,
    CantViajes int null,
    Domicilio varchar(500) not null,
    Edad int not null,
    Estado bit null
)
go 
Create Table Tarjetas(
    
    ID_Tarjeta bigint not null primary key identity(1,1),
    Numero_Tarjeta varchar(16) not null unique,
    ID_Usuario bigint not null foreign key references Usuarios(ID_Usuario),
    FechaAlta datetime not null,
    Saldo money not null,
    Estado bit not null

)
go
Create Table Colectivos(
    
    ID_Colectivos bigint not null primary key identity(1,1),
    NumeroInterno bigint not null unique
)
go
Create Table LineaColectivos(
    
    ID_LineaColectivos bigint not null primary key identity(1,1),
    CodigoLinea bigint not null unique,
    NombreEmpresa varchar(100) not null unique,
    Domicilio varchar(500) not null
)
go
Create Table Viajes(
    
    ID_Viajes bigint not null primary key identity(1,1),
    CodigoViaje varchar(16) not null unique,
    FechaHoraViaje datetime not null,
    NumeroInternoColectivo bigint not null foreign key references Colectivos(NumeroInterno),
    CodigoLinea bigint not null foreign key references LineaColectivos(CodigoLinea),
    Numero_Tarjeta varchar(16) not null foreign key references Tarjetas(Numero_Tarjeta),
    Importe money not null,
    ID_Usuario bigint not null foreign key references Usuarios(ID_Usuario)

)
go
Create Table Movimientos(
    ID_Movimiento bigint not null primary key identity(1,1),
    Numero_Movimiento varchar(16) not null unique,
    FechaMovimiento datetime not null,
    Numero_Tarjeta varchar(16) not null foreign key references Tarjetas(Numero_Tarjeta),
    Importe money not null,
    TipoMovimiento char not null CHECK (TipoMovimiento IN ('D', 'C'))

)
```

Comment: ¿Por qué haces eso en un trigger en vez de hacerlo en un procedimiento almacenado?

Comment: Porque mi profesor quiere que use trigger

Comment: Por favor, mové tu código de snippets a bloques de código (con triples acentos graves (```) una línea antes y una después del código). Los snippets son solo para código HTML/CSS/JS, ya que pueden ser ejecutables en la pregunta. En el caso de los scripts de SQL, no.

Answer (score 0):

El error principal de tu código se encuentra al obtener los datos de la tarjeta.

```
-- Busco el estado y saldo
Select @Estado = @Estado, 
       @Saldo = Saldo 
From Tarjetas 
Where @Numero_Tarjeta = 442983422
```

Mientras uses la tarjeta 442983422 para insertar valores, la variable @Saldo regresará un valor (el último que lea aunque no sabemos cual sea porque no hay un orden establecido) y la variable @Estado mantendrá su valor porque se está asignando a si misma (aunque en este caso siempre será nulo porque no tiene ninguna otra asignación).

Sin embargo, no recomiendo que manejes los triggers con tantas variables. Eso limita tu código a trabajar una fila a la vez y eso es lento. En cambio, necesitas generar tu código para trabajar con cualquier cantidad de filas como sea necesario. También es una buena práctica el darle un buen formato al código para priorizar la legibilidad. Recuerda que no te cobran los espacios en blanco.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_AgregarViaje ON Viajes
AFTER INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

            --Verifique que la tarjeta se encuentre activa.
            --Verifique que el saldo de la tarjeta sea suficiente para realizar el viaje.
            --Registre el viaje
            --Registre el movimiento
            --Descuente el stock de la tarjeta

            --Registre el viaje
            INSERT INTO Viajes(
                    CodigoViaje,
                    FechaHoraViaje,
                    NumeroInternoColectivo,
                    CodigoLinea,
                    Numero_Tarjeta,
                    Importe,
                    ID_Usuario)
            SELECT  i.CodigoViaje, 
                    GETDATE(),
                    i.NumeroInternoColectivo,
                    i.CodigoLinea, 
                    i.Numero_Tarjeta, 
                    i.Importe, 
                    i.ID_Usuario
            FROM inserted AS i
            JOIN Tarjetas AS t ON i.Numero_Tarjeta = t.Numero_Tarjeta
            --Verifique que la tarjeta se encuentre activa.
            WHERE t.Estado = 1
            --Verifique que el saldo de la tarjeta sea suficiente para realizar el viaje.
            AND   t.Saldo >= i.Importe;

            IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
                THROW 51000, 'La tarjeta no está activa o no tiene suficiente saldo.', 1; 
                    
            --Registre el movimiento (esto lo puedes completar tú para aprender)

            --Descuente el stock de la tarjeta
            UPDATE t SET
                saldo = t.Saldo - i.Importe
            From inserted AS i
            JOIN Tarjetas AS t ON i.Numero_Tarjeta = t.Numero_Tarjeta
            WHERE t.Estado = 1
            AND   t.Saldo >= i.Importe;

        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        THROW; -- Es importante notificar que existió un error y no solo descartar el proceso.
    END CATCH
END
```

Comment: ¿No es mejor verificar en primer lugar si hay saldo suficiente, si no lo hay lanzar la excepción, en caso contrario hacer el `INSERT` y el `UPDATE` del saldo? Aunque la verdad, no veo el sentido pedagógico de pedir todo esto en un `TRIGGER`. En fin...

Comment: Es mejor hacer la validación durante la misma acción para evitar problemas de concurrencia. Aunque es probable que siga siendo un problema. Concuerdo contigo en que no tiene sentido hacer todo esto en un trigger y el profesor posiblemente no tiene mucha experiencia programando.

Answer (score -1):

estaba probando el código que me pasaste y me tira este error "Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Procedure TR_AgregarViaje, Line 15 [Batch Start Line 83]
Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ__Viajes__50D7BC1328A39F6B'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Viajes'. The duplicate key value is (333)."
Estuve leyendo lo que me dijiste y tenes razón, estoy usando muchas variables. Lo volví a hacer de 0, guiándome de tu código y me quedo así:

```
  CREATE TRIGGER TR_AgregarViaje ON VIAJES
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
            
            DECLARE @SALDO MONEY
            DECLARE @ESTADO BIT

            SELECT @ESTADO = Estado, @SALDO = Saldo 
            FROM Tarjetas 
            WHERE Numero_Tarjeta = (SELECT Numero_Tarjeta FROM inserted)

            IF (@ESTADO = 1 AND @SALDO>=(SELECT Importe FROM inserted))
            BEGIN
            -- ACTUALIZO EL SALDO
                UPDATE Tarjetas 
                SET Saldo-=(SELECT Importe FROM inserted)
                WHERE Numero_Tarjeta = (SELECT Numero_Tarjeta FROM inserted)
            -- REGISTRO EL MOVIMIENTO
                DECLARE @Numero_Movimiento BIGINT = (SELECT CAST(MAX(Numero_Movimiento) AS BIGINT) FROM Movimientos) 
                INSERT INTO Movimientos(
                                    Numero_Movimiento,
                                    FechaMovimiento,
                                    Numero_Tarjeta,
                                    Importe,
                                    TipoMovimiento
                                        )
                            VALUES (
                                    @Numero_Movimiento +1,
                                    getdate(),
                        (SELECT Numero_Tarjeta FROM inserted),
                        (SELECT Importe FROM inserted),
                                    'D'
                                    )
                                        
                                    
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                RAISERROR('TARJETA SIN SALDO SUFICIENTE O DADA DE BAJA', 16, 1)
            END

        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END CATCH
END
```

Perdón si el formato para pasar código esta mal, pero es que soy nuevo en stackoverflow y apenas tengo 2 publicaciones, encima la primera es de hace un año xd

Este trigger me dejo insertar los viajes y movimientos correctamente, aunque no se si es la forma mas optima

Comment: El error es porque estás usando un número de viaje repetido y ese debe ser un valor único en la columna. Por otro lado, no hagas tanto subqueries, para eso tienes los JOINs. En el insert sigues insertando una sola fila y no está preparado para recibir múltples filas al mismo tiempo. Puede parecer algo innecesario hasta que no lo es. Usa el método `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`

Comment: Tu código también tendrá problemas por concurrencia (no pasará en un ejercicio pero sí en la vida real). Todo lo que te digo es para que puedas aprender, espero no lo tomes a mal.

Comment: Esto debe ser una edición a tu pregunta. Borra esta _no-respuesta_.